# Grunt, Live Reload with Jekyll Serve

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, livereload

I'm familiar with the Connect server method with a watch task which signals a Jekyll Build. It's good, but I'd prefer the built in Jekyll Serve which has the fast regeneration instead of build.

Is it possible to use Jekyll Serve with Live Reload in Grunt? Essentially, every time you make a change, Jekyll Serve would say "Regenerating" and you could see the changes in the browser without a refresh.

Happy to use the Chrome Live Reload extension too.

Note: I know this can be achieved using Guard, but I was hoping for a whole Grunt solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I got this to work:

The problem is that both `jekyll serve` and `grunt watch` need to run in parallel. What I did was to create two grunt tasks and run them in two separate terminal windows.
I have the following setup:

- a `_src` directory where I edit the raw source files
- an `asset` directory where I have images and such
- a `build` directory that gets populated by grunt and inside which jekyll is run

First, I run the `grunt dev` task. This taskfirst deletes the build directory, then copies the necessary source files and finally cds into my build directory and calls jekyll:

```sh
cd build && jekyll serve --livereload
```

This task is configured as follows:

```js
grunt.registerTask(
  'assembledev',
  [
    'copy:src',
    'copy:assets'
  ]
);
grunt.registerTask(
  'dev',
  [
    'clean',
    'assembledev',
    'exec:serve'
  ]
);
```

Then, in a separate terminal, I run `grunt watch`. Watch is configured as follows:

```js
watch {
  src: {
    files: ['{_src,assets}/**/*.{js,css,html,php}'],
    tasks: ['assembledev']
  }
}
```

Now, whenever I change a source file, the updated file gets copied to the build directory and then recognized by jekyll as a changed file.

The two terminal windows feel like a bit of a hack but that way, I can see the output of both `grunt watch` and `jekyll serve`. Also, I can easily quit either process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

In principle, you could get away with one terminal window by adding an `&` to the end of the jekyll serve command in order to run jekyll in the background (`cd build && jekyll serve --livereload &`) and run `watch` within the same grunt task like this:

```js
grunt.registerTask(
  'dev',
  [
    'clean',
    'assembledev',
    'exec:servebg',
    'watch'
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) which is

> Yeoman helps you to kickstart new projects, prescribing best practices and tools to help you stay productive.

as described. There are lots of generators in yeoman's homepage which helps you create your project quickly. By the way, we are looking for a generator which includes Jekyll project is served by Grunt, [jeklyrrb](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) is a great solution. Despite it comes with Grunt, it also helps you with

- > Automatic CSS vendor prefixing with Autoprefixer
- > Default Jekyll or HTML5 Boilerplate templates Compass, Sass, or vanilla CSS Built in
- > preview server with BrowserSync
- > Code quality checks with Jshint and/or
- > CoffeeLint, CssLint, and jekyll doctor
- > ...

There are some steps you should do and possible problems you will face during installation of jekyllrb. Those are steps how i have solved them so far

### Installation

```
npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower

npm install -g generator-jekyllrb
```

after installed yeoman, its requirements(grunt and bower) and generator globally, create your working directory and cd in it. Than start yeoman:

```
yo jeykllrb
```

### Problem

*Path/sudo problems while installing gems.*

### Solution

*Installing rvm*

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

### Problem

pygments deprecation problem

### Solution

change

```
pygments: true
```

to

```
highlighter: pygments
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `jekyll serve`, you can use the Grunt plugin [grunt-jekyll](https://github.com/dannygarcia/grunt-jekyll) in combination with [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and any of a few Grunt plugins to "serve" your compiled files like [browser-sync](https://github.com/BrowserSync/grunt-browser-sync) or [grunt-express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express).

Your `Gruntfiles.js` would look a little like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        jekyll: {
            working: {
              options: {
                config: '_config.yml',
                drafts: true
              }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            jekyll: {
                files: [
                    '**/*.md',
                    '*.html',
                    '*.md',
                    '!_site/**/*' // Stops watch from triggering again after Jekyll compiles
                ],
                tasks: ['jekyll']
            },

            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        }

        browserSync: {
            dev: {
                bsFiles: {
                    src : [
                        'css/*.css',
                        ' *.html',
                        '**/*.html'
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    watchTask: true,
                    server: './_site'
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jekyll');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jekyll', 'browserSync', 'watch']);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is a similar setup to which I mentioned in the post, Grunt Jekyll, watch with Connect server. Again, trying to use Jekyll Serve and not a build everytime you make a change.

Comment: @Rhys yeah I get that; unfortunately, what you're asking for pretty much requires a rebuild. You could use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to run the `Jekyll Serve` command, but it does basically the same thing.